# How to pass {!Case.ID} to PageReference

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

I am having issues understanding how to pass the {!Case.Id} value to a PageReference in a visualforce class.

My VF Page is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="escalateToJiraController" >


<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Escalate Case" mode="edit">


        <apex:PageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" onclick="window.close()"/>
        </apex:PageBlockButtons>


        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Case.CaseNumber}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Escalation_Priority__c}"/>                    
                <apex:inputField style="width: 500px" value="{!Case.Escalation_Subject__c}"/>

                <apex:outputText label="Instructions" escape="false" value="
                   Please provide a complete problem description. Provide all relevant information including hostnames"/>
                <apex:outputText label=" " escape="false" value="
                   and specific times for each relevant event. Below that, please paste, and complete, the appropriate"/> 
                <apex:outputText label=" " escape="false" value="
                   Escalation Template from the CS Debugging Guide."/>                                    

                <apex:inputField style="width: 500px; height: 500px" value="{!Case.Escalation_Description__c}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

My Controller:

```
    public class escalateToJiraController {

    ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    public escalateToJiraController(ApexPages.StandardController con){
        controller = con;
      }


    public PageReference save() {
        controller.save();
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('http://somewebsite.com/sfdc/jira-test.php?token=8675309&case={!Case.Id}');
        return pageRef;

    }
}
```

I think I need to use getParameters(), but am not really finding examples that I am able to make much sense of. Pretty new at the VF/Apex stuff.

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the parameter explicitly. My favorite way to do this is using getParameters:

```
Pagereference ref = new Pagereference('http://somesite...');
ref.getParameters().put('case',controller.getId());
return ref;
```

Comment: This was the easiest way to accomplish my goal. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can add querystring parameters to the page reference by using [MY PAGEREF].getParameters().put(key, value)

```
Case myCase { get; set; }

public escalateToJiraController(ApexPages.StandardController con){
    controller = con;
    myCase = (Case)con.getRecord();
}    

public PageReference save() {
    controller.save();
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('http://somewebsite.com/sfdc/jira-test.php');
    pageRef.getParameters().put('token','8675309');
    pageRef.getParameters().put('case',myCase.id);
    return pageRef;

}
```

Comment: This was good - but I like the short had way for this particular problem (see answer). Thanks!